# How to find the PDF of a random variable through another variable? (relations are known; both are discreet)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

As I was preparing for my examination, I came across this question:

**Let X be the random variable, taking the values as: 1, 2, 3, 4...n. Let P (X = n) = $(\frac{1}{2})^2$. Let Y = 1 when X is even and Y = -1 when X is odd. Find the PDF of Y.**

From this, I could derive the PDF of X with its probabilities, and established that Y = $(-1)^2$. However, I am unable to get the probabilities of Y as I do not understand how to employ the information I have about X in this case.

All help is appreciated.

I realize that similar questions have been asked before, but from what I gather, they are mostly for the continuous, rather than discrete. Also, I do not seem to understand them.

Comment: " *From this, I could derive the PDF of X with its probabilities* " What have you found out?

Comment: Nothing much, frankly whatever is given. I tried to come up with GPs and all, but they didn't really help me. I am not able to identify any other relation as for the one I already found. Is the question incorrect?

Comment: From what's given, $$\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb P(X=n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac n4$$ which clearly doesn't sum to one. So $X$ does not have a properly defined probability distribution.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks a bunch! Well, if you've posted it as an answer, I would've selected it, but kudos to you anyway.

Comment: It isn't a proper answer to your question because we can't say anything about $Y$. There is something wrong in the question about the definition of $\mathbb P(X=n)$. Are you sure you copied it down correctly?

Comment: @Math1000 I am pretty certain I haven't made any errors in the copying the question. Although, there were some errors in theother questions of the assignment, and finally the prof ended up cancelling the question today, I would still love to get a defined answer (if possible, that is).

Comment: It is not possible for the question as written, as I have already explained.